# Documentation for SupervisingRouteController

Tags: apache-camel, paho

I have MQTT route like below

```
from("paho:mytopic?brokerUrl=tcp://0.0.0.0:1883&clientId=ipc)
.routeId("myroute")
.to("log:my?showAll=true&multiline=true");
```

it starts only if broker is available and after that if it lost connectivity with broker it handle it very well and resume.

But my concern is how i can start first time if broker is not available?

I searched on google and got to know  "SupervisingRouteController" might help in this regard, But no document is available how i can use it.
By some hit and trial i reach this point but what further i can do as no document available

```
final Main main = new Main();
main.addRouteBuilder(new MyMqttRoute());
SupervisingRouteController controller = main.getCamelContexts().get(0).getRouteController().unwrap(SupervisingRouteController.class);
main.run();
```

Comment: Have you considered using `paho` component's `lazyStartProducer` option?

Comment: I am using paho as consumer

Answer (score 1):

Here are two unit test cases that shows usage of SupervisingRouteController.
[SupervisingRouteControllerTest.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/SupervisingRouteControllerTest.java)
[SupervisingRouteControllerRestartTest.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/SupervisingRouteControllerRestartTest.java)

These may be helpful in understanding its usage.

Comment: These unit test are for SpringBoot apps, For camel-main there is a JIRA about making configuring
this out of the box better
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13535

Comment: Thank you. It is still an open issue unfortunately. Let's see if @Claus Ibsen/others has any say on this.